# PHP read and write JSON from file

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON in a file `list.txt`:

```
{
"bgates":{"first":"Bill","last":"Gates"},
"sjobs":{"first":"Steve","last":"Jobs"}
}
```

How do I add `"bross":{"first":"Bob","last":"Ross"}` to my file using PHP?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

$user = "bross";
$first = "Bob";
$last = "Ross";

$file = "list.txt";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));

$json[$user] = array("first" => $first, "last" => $last);

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));

?>
```

Which gives me a Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on this line:

```
$json[$user] = array("first" => $first, "last" => $last);
```

I'm using PHP5.2. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The clue is in the error message - if you look at the documentation for [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) note that it can take a second param, which controls whether it returns an array or an object - it defaults to object.

So change your call to

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
```

And it'll return an associative array and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 29):

The sample for reading and writing JSON in PHP:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),TRUE);

$json[$user] = array("first" => $first, "last" => $last);

file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
```

Comment: The second argument to json_encode is not a boolean, so it's wrong to write `json_encode($json, TRUE)`.

Comment: Per the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the second argument IS a boolean.

Comment: @PedroLobito - I was looking at the code given by 4EACH. There the only function that is used with the second argument as a boolean is json_decode. json_encode IS used later but without a second argument. Of course I can see that the author edited the code. It is unknown if that edit was to correct the use of the function.

Answer (score 8):

Or just use $json as an object:

```
$json->$user = array("first" => $first, "last" => $last);
```

This is how it is returned without the second parameter (as an instance of [stdClass](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/)).

Answer (score 7):

You need to make the decode function return an array by passing in the `true` parameter.

`json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);`

Answer (score 3):

Try using second parameter for json_decode function:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you to get the contents of `list.txt` file

```
$headers = array('http'=>array('method'=>'GET','header'=>'Content: type=application/json \r\n'.'$agent \r\n'.'$hash'));

$context=stream_context_create($headers);

$str = file_get_contents("list.txt",FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH,$context);

$str=utf8_encode($str);

$str=json_decode($str,true);

print_r($str);
```

Comment: I just get Array as my output from that

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the JSON data in well defined formate you can modify the code as:

```
file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json,TRUE));


$headers = array('http'=>array('method'=>'GET','header'=>'Content: type=application/json \r\n'.'$agent \r\n'.'$hash'));

$context=stream_context_create($headers);

$str = file_get_contents("list.txt",FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH,$context);

$str1=utf8_encode($str);

$str1=json_decode($str1,true);



foreach($str1 as $key=>$value)
{

    echo "key is: $key.\n";

    echo "values are: \t";
        foreach ($value as $k) {

        echo " $k. \t";
        # code...
    }
        echo "<br></br>";
        echo "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to create json format it had to be in this format for it to read:

```
[ 
  {
    "":"",
    "":[
     {
       "":"",
       "":""
     }
    ]
  }
]
```