# How to change a value permanently in another PHP file

Tags: php, file-io

I am using a configuration file for something I am working on. In that configuration file, I have a line like `$twelveHourTimeEnabled = true;`. I want to be able to switch true to false in this but am not sure the way to change just that line from `true` to `false`.

Currently, I am using separate files that switches the two, but I know this must be grossly inefficient.

```
$fn = "config.php"; 
$file = fopen($fn, "w+"); 
$size = filesize($fn); 

$twelveHourConfig = "12hrconfig.php";
$twelveHourConfigFile = file_get_contents($twelveHourConfig);

fwrite($file, $twelveHourConfigFile);

fclose($file);
```

How would I switch the true value to false, or vice versa without requiring two other files to read in?

EDIT:

This project is a PHP plug-in for a desktop app (Alfred App for Mac OS X) which returns TV information to the user wherever they are. For this reason, this action is being done when a keyword is called. For this reason there is no way to use a database, etc.

EDIT 2:
Sorry, I have no experience with JSON or other file IO operations as I normally deal with CRUD. Also, know that I have no control over the user machines, etc. This needs to function with PHP that would be installed by default when someone installs Mac OS X. Nothing more. If someone can explain JSON I would be happy to use it, I just don't know anything about it, how to use it, etc.

Comment: the context is not clear, but it looks like a 'time' thing, so why not a db with a timestamp?

Comment: Well, you can use a ini configuration, xml or json file instead, it's more safe and easy.

Comment: Added to what mario said; you should keep in mind that if that exact phrase (`$twelveHourTimeEnabled = true;`) would be somewhere in a comment or an if-else construct it might ruin the purpose. Always check if there are more matches and then handle them correctly. If possible, it's better to store such settings in a database tho, it's cleaner/more readable and easier accessible. Off-course that is off-topic, but just saying.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sadly that isn't an option as this is not a web based application, but an extension to Alfred App for Mac OS X. For this reason, the config file is being used to allow a keyword, set by the user, to trigger the change in the config file for easier use.

Comment: I'd store all your data in a config file, not a PHP file.  JSON is pretty easy to use for this, as you can open the file, read it in, [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it into an object or array, modify items, then [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it and write the file out again

Comment: I agree with the JSON idea.  There is also XML and SQLite, but I think JSON will be the easiest, IMO

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with JSON and for two lines of configuration by the time the extension is done, I really don't need overkill like this. I just don't know how to search in other files and change info as I've never handled any form of file IO before, only CRUD.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OS X in any detail, but your last comment about this needing to function in a standard environment makes me wonder - doesn't OS X protect binary directories from write operations?  Also, [PHP read and write JSON from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858848/php-read-and-write-json-from-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think JSON is overkill.  You really only need four PHP methods for this - 2 for reading/writing files, and 2 for encoding/decoding JSON.  Heck, you don't even need to understand JSON to use it as described below, but it might be nice to be able to look at the configfilename and read it, so you could learn a bit of JSON as you go ;)

The basics are let's say you have an array with your config in it, e.g.:

```
$configArray['key'] = 'value';
```

To write this out in json:

```
file_put_contents('configfilename', json_encode($configArray));
```

To read the file:

```
$configArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('configfilename'), true);
```

Note the second argument to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) has been explicitly set to true, so that $configArray will be an associative array.  That's a personal preference; by default it'll be an object.

(This answer is based heavily on this question regarding [reading/writing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858848/php-read-and-write-json-from-file).)

Answer (score 1):

For configuration files I would recommend the following setup.

Let's assume this is the contents of `config.php`:

```
<?php

return array(
    'opt1' => 'value1',
    'opt2' => 'value2',
);
```

Then, to load this configuration:

```
<?php

$config = require 'config.php';
// $config['opt1'] == 'value1'
```

Modifying the configuration can be done by changing the array and writing it back:

```
$config['opt2'] = 'value2 but different'; 

file_put_contents('config.php', '<?php return ' . var_export($config, true) . ';');
```

To swap configuration files in your case, you could simply use `copy()`:

```
copy('12hrconfig.php', 'config.php');
```

Comment: Thanks. I just thought there must be an easier way to simply change the value from true to false (or vice versa). That would allow me to remove the two other configuration files and reduce the overall size of the extension.

Comment: @kkirsche I've added an example how to modify the configuration and writing it back into the file.