# Do you really need MySQL to host PHP files?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I know w3schools is not the best source, but I use it when I need a quick look at a language/technology.

Fetching Data From a PHP Server Running MySQL - the file being fetched is customers_mysql.php, which is just a php file in json format

```
{"records":[{"name":"haha", "country":"lolz"}]}
```

[Here is the link](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp)

I'm confused, as far I as know you don't really need MySQL to host PHP files, just the PHP interpreter, so is it misleading when they include words 'running MySQL'?

Comment: No you don't need to be running MySQL to fetch a file, Most likely they were copying and pasting during documentation

Comment: be hard to find a host with php but without mysql.

Comment: They are merely stating the facts there, http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php requests a resource from a server running php and MySQL and http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_sql.aspx fetches a resource from a server running .net and an sql server. And they provide the server-side scripts for both as well. If anything it shows you that it matters zipdeedoodah to the client how the response is created.

Comment: Thanks. And of course there are at least several people who will downvote without giving a reason why.

Comment: @VolkerK, that's true, but because they are fetching data one may misunderstand that MySQL is needed too.

Comment: PHP can utilize many different database systems and MySQL is just one of them. One small clarification regarding customers_mysql.php. It is not a php file in json format. It is a php file that returns json.

Comment: imo, the words they phrase `running MYSQL` is just saying they are using MYSQL...it could be `running SQL server`, `running MSSQL`, `running PostgreSQL` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as long as you don't need to fetch data from it.

Answer (score 1):

All w3schools is doing is telling you how to fetch JSON format data from a PHP file using angular.  They are also showing what that file would contain if you wanted to fetch data from a MySQL server using PHP.  PHP is connecting to the database and then printing the result in JSON format.

Hopefully this helps out the confusion.  PHP and MySQL are 2 different technologies but work very well together for dynamic applications.  Of course you can run PHP without MySQL but if you wanted to store data you would probably want a database engine if not SQLite.

Comment: It's also more than possible to skip using any SQL-oriented database and instead utilize .json files containing JSON objects. They're similarly secure since you require access to the server to view them and their contents, but don't require the longer access scripts that SQL-oriented databases do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858848/php-read-and-write-json-from-file