# JSON .txt File in Data to Convert Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get json data from a website. I then save this data to the `.txt` file.

```
{
  m: [
    {
      d: '08.01.2015',
      m: [
        [
          2875678,
          'id1',
          77,
          'id2',
          '100',
          0,
          '21:20',
          '',
          '',
          '3',
          '',
          '1',
          '-',
          '1.09',
          '2.06',
          '2.05',
          '1.40',
          '92334',
          {
            tId: 92334
          },
          '\u0130S1',
          '14',
          '20'
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The contents of the .txt file are as above.I want to make this .txt file a array.But when using `json_decode` the result is blank.

```
$file= fopen("test.txt", "r");
if( $file == false ) {
    echo ( "error!" );
    exit();
}else {
    while (!feof($file)) {
    $read = fgets($file);
    $decode = json_decode($read, true);
    print_r($decode);
    } 
}
fclose($file);
```

How can I convert it into an array?
EDİT: data saved with this code.

```
$data = cURL($url);
$urlHandle     = _fwrite($data);
$datam        = $data;
$data        = json_decode($datam,true);

function _fwrite($data1)
{
    $file    = fopen('test.txt','w');
    fwrite($file,$data1);
    fclose($file);
  }
```

Comment: You may refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858848/php-read-and-write-json-from-file

Comment: The thing is that's not JSON but a Javascript object

Comment: The problem is the JSON String is not valid, put it through `jsonlint.com`

Comment: @Borjante, What should I do for this?

Comment: Look up `json_last_error_msg();` and `echo json_last_error();`

Comment: Please see my answer, you need to json_encode the response from server before saving it into file

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Output: `Error: Parse error on line 1:
{ m: [{  d: '08.01.20
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'`

Comment: Show us how you retrieve and save this data to the file in the first place

Comment: EXACTLY! Its not valid JSON. So we now need to work out if you damagaed it when saving it to a file, or whether it was delivered to you as rubbish

Comment: Show us the code you used to get this into a file please

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I added the subject.

Comment: @Borjante, I added the subject.

Comment: Can you show the content of $data from the curl request?

Comment: @kiner_shah, I read it but I did not get results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your band-aid solution.  This works on your provided sample input.  It will work ...until it doesn't because of anomalies that are possible but not included in your post.

You need to take the time to isolate where and why your input data is malformed.  Good applications are built from strong/stable foundations -- yours is not yet able to enjoy such stability.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DlFt0))

```
$badjson=<<<BADJSON
{
  m: [
    {
      d: '08.01.2015',
      m: [
        [
          2875678,
          'id1',
          77,
          'id2',
          '100',
          0,
          '21:20',
          '',
          '',
          '3',
          '',
          '1',
          '-',
          '1.09',
          '2.06',
          '2.05',
          '1.40',
          '92334',
          {
            tId: 92334
          },
          '\u0130S1',
          '14',
          '20'
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
BADJSON;

var_export(json_decode(preg_replace(["~^\s+\K\w+(?=:)|^\s+\K\d+(?=,?\s*$)~m","~'~"],['"$0"','"'],$badjson),true));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'm' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'd' => '08.01.2015',
      'm' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => '2875678',
          1 => 'id1',
          2 => '77',
          3 => 'id2',
          4 => '100',
          5 => '0',
          6 => '21:20',
          7 => '',
          8 => '',
          9 => '3',
          10 => '',
          11 => '1',
          12 => '-',
          13 => '1.09',
          14 => '2.06',
          15 => '2.05',
          16 => '1.40',
          17 => '92334',
          18 => 
          array (
            'tId' => 92334,
          ),
          19 => 'İS1',
          20 => '14',
          21 => '20',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```